# how to read image in Ada?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, ada

I'm new in Ada programming language, I want to read and manipulate images in Ada without binding other libraries like opencv.
Is there any way to read images in Ada? Or convert it to pixel values (RGB) especially bitmap images. I made the above type for saving bitmap image pixels but i dont know how to read the image and fill my image type.

```
type Byte is range 0..255;

   for Byte'Size use 8;

   type Pixel is record

   R:Byte;

   G:Byte;

   B:Byte;

   end record;

   for Pixel'Size use 24;

   type Image is array(Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Pixel;

   Pragma Pack(Image);
```

Comment: Your question is close to being closed for being too broad, out of scope, or unclear. Since you have already defined a “proper type” to store the image, you could improve the question by posting *that* and asking how to fill it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an existing library?

Comment: I will gonna do some image processing on GIMME2 board using binding libraries is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

You can see two examples for reading a complete file on Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#Ada

Once you have read the file, it is "just" a matter of interpreting the file according to the relevant file format.

Answer (score 1):

**Define bmp headers**

[Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about header.

```
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
package BMP is
type Header is record
    Signature : Integer_16;
    Size      : Integer_32; -- File size in bytes
    Reserved1 : Integer_16;
    Reserved2 : Integer_16;
    Offset    : Integer_32; -- Start address in bytes where the image data can be found.
end record;
```

[Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about info header

```
type Info is record
    Struct_Size   : Integer_32;
    Width         : Integer_32; -- Image width in pixels
    Height        : Integer_32; -- Image hieght in pixels
    Planes        : Integer_16;
    Pixel_Size    : Integer_16; -- Bits per pixel
    Compression   : Integer_32; -- Zero means no compression
    Image_Size    : Integer_32; -- Size of the image data in bytes
    PPMX          : Integer_32; -- Pixels per meter in x led
    PPMY          : Integer_32; -- Pixels per meter in y led
    Palette_Size  : Integer_32; -- Number of colors
    Important     : Integer_32;
end record;
```

**There are many types of pixels**.
Here are two types:

```
type Pixel_G8 is new Integer_8; -- 8 bit pixel grayscale
type Image_G8 is array (Integer range <>) of Pixel_G8;

type Pixel_ARGB32 is record -- 32 bit pixel (alpha, red, green, blue)
    A, R, G, B : Integer_8; -- 8 bit * 4 = 32 bit
end record;
type Image_ARGB32 is array (Integer range <>) of Pixel_ARGB32;
```

**How to get the data into types**

*Ada.Streams.Stream_IO* allows us to read into different type from same file object by using the Read attribute. More [info](http://www.infres.enst.fr/~pautet/Ada95/chap24.htm) about different IOs.

```
with Ada; use Ada;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Streams.Stream_IO;
use Ada.Streams;
with BMP;

procedure Test_BMP is
   File   : Stream_IO.File_Type;
   Stream : Stream_IO.Stream_Access;
   Header : BMP.Header;
   Info   : BMP.Info;
   Name   : constant String := "lena512.bmp";
begin

   Stream_IO.Open(File, Stream_IO.In_File, Name);
   Stream := Stream_IO.Stream(File);

   BMP.Header'Read(Stream, Header);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Signature " & Header.Signature'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Size " & Header.Size'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Reserved1 " & Header.Reserved1'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Reserved2 " & Header.Reserved2'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Offset " & Header.Offset'Img);

   BMP.Info'Read(Stream, Info);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Struct_Size " & Info.Struct_Size'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Width " & Info.Width'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Height " & Info.Height'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Planes " & Info.Planes'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Pixel_Size " & Info.Pixel_Size'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Compression " & Info.Compression'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Image_Size " & Info.Image_Size'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("PPMX " & Info.PPMX'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("PPMY " & Info.PPMY'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Palette_Size " & Info.Palette_Size'Img);
   Text_IO.Put_Line("Important " & Info.Important'Img);

   delay 2.0;

   -- Move read pointer to where the image data starts.
   Stream_IO.Set_Index(File, Stream_IO.Positive_Count(Header.Offset));

   declare
      subtype Image is BMP.Image_G8(1..Integer(Info.Image_Size));
      I : Image;
   begin
      Image'Read(Stream, I);
      Stream_IO.Close(File);
      for P of I loop
         Text_IO.Put(P'Img);
      end loop;
   end;

end;
```

**Sidenote**

If *Info.Compression* is not zero you will have to decompress the image data. I don't know how currently so I will not explain. But you can stick to uncompressed bmp.

I dont know how to check if the format is RGB or GBR or any format. The closest I know to intepret pixel format is to check pixel size, but does not show the order of the color components.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bind other libraries, you will have to write your own reader and store the data in pixel format. Then you can do whatever you want with it.
Depending on the input format, this is either an easy or relatively complex task.
If you are mostly interested in BMP files, luck is on your side, because it is a particularly simple format and consists basically of a header followed by the data. I did a reader in C myself years ago and it was rather simple.
You find the format definition everywhere on the web, for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) on Wikipedia. If I remember correctly, BMP images are stored "bottom up" so you will have to invert the Y rows when you read the picture, since most people prefer the top line to be first in an array or whatever structure you chose.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes i'm dealing with bmp images but the problem is  i'm new in Ada and i dont know how to read the image i created a proper type to store the image but i dont know how to read it. if i could read the image then the rest will be easy

Comment: Having looked at the Wikipedia ref, I have to say that reading a BMP doesn’t look particularly simple!